# Change image after random amount of time, but only after page refresh

Tags: javascript

For example, an image can change to another random image in a set every 1-2 hours (or stay the same image). However the image doesn't change immediately, only after the page is refreshed. Only refreshing the page will not change the image, it still depends on time.

This would be used for an easter egg on my site. Unfortunately I don't really know any javascript.

Additionally, if it's possible: there are two image sets, and it pulls from a different set depending on the time of the day. (e.g. day/night)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have a set of 4 images, 2 for the day and 2 for the night:

- day1.jpg
- day2.jpg
- night1.jpg
- night2.jpg

You could define:

- *day*, when hours is from 6:00 to 17:59
- *night*, else

and implement a random logic (with 50% of chance between the two indexes) like this:

```js
function getRandomImgSrc() {
  let hours = new Date().getHours();
  let dayOrNight = hours >= 6 && hours < 18 ? "day" : "night";
  let index = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "1" : "2";
  let imgSrc = dayOrNight + index + ".jpg";
  console.log(imgSrc);
  return imgSrc;
}
document.getElementById("randomImage").setAttribute("src", getRandomImgSrc());
```

```css
#randomImage {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="randomImage">
```

Comment: Works well for the day/night sets - but seems to change depending on refresh, is it possible for the images to change depending on time passed *and* page refresh? (i.e. image changes after 1 hour passes, page refresh makes it visible)

Comment: @nathopestu you should create a new question, specifying and clarifying every single request.